# Eclipse - The supplied phased action failed with an exception

Tags: java

The supplied phased action failed with an exception.
A problem occurred configuring root project 'mcp-reborn'.
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
Using insecure protocols with repositories, without explicit opt-in, is unsupported. Switch Maven repository 'maven(http://files.minecraftforge.net/maven)' to redirect to a secure protocol (like HTTPS) or allow insecure protocols. See https://docs.gradle.org/7.4/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.UrlArtifactRepository.html#org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.UrlArtifactRepository:allowInsecureProtocol for more details.     MCP-Reborn-1.16     line 0  Gradle Error Marker

can someone help with this error?